# Python String Format not working as expected when ran in a script

Tags: python

I creating a python script, which one of its functions is to run a shell command. When using the REPL to format the string that builds the command, it works as expected. However, when running it in the script function itself, the formatting gets messed up! Has anyone come across this issue and knows why is it happening? For the example below, I've switched the command execution to a simple print method, so I'll be able to get the immediate outcome of the formatting.
Details below:

variables:

- rifs_names - type 'list', containing two items of type 'str'
- server_name - type 'str'

function:

```
def get_rifs_status():
    for rifs in rifs_names:
        print 'mco shell run -I {0} "sc qc {1} 5000"'.format(server_name, rifs)
```

REPL output (Good):

```
mco shell run -I <server_name> "sc qc <rifs> 5000"
mco shell run -I <server_name> "sc qc <rifs> 5000"
```

Script output (Messed-up):

```
 5000"ell run -I <server_name> "sc qc <rifs>
 5000"ell run -I <server_name> "sc qc <rifs>
```

I've tried endless options of formatting, nothing works.. 
I'm really going crazy here, any help would be appreciated.

Here are the details about my python env, just in case it's needed:

```
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Jun 18 2012, 14:18:47) 
[GCC 4.4.6 20110731 (Red Hat 4.4.6-3)] on linux2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `rifs` values include a *carriage return character*, `\r`, putting the 'write position' back at the start of the line, so the `5000"` part is written there.

Strip this character:

```
print 'mco shell run -I {0} "sc qc {1} 5000"'.format(server_name, rifs.rstrip('\r'))
```

Demo:

```
>>> server_name = '<server_name>'
>>> rifs = '<rifs>\r'
>>> print 'mco shell run -I {0} "sc qc {1} 5000"'.format(server_name, rifs)
 5000"ell run -I <server_name> "sc qc <rifs>
>>> print 'mco shell run -I {0} "sc qc {1} 5000"'.format(server_name, rifs.rstrip('\r'))
mco shell run -I <server_name> "sc qc <rifs> 5000"
```

Comment: Brilliant!! Can't believe I haven't thought of this. Thanks a lot for the quick assistance!! :-) I'll mark this as the answer..